# WordPress newsletter plugin

Tags: wordpress, newsletter

I am searching for **WordPress newsletter plugin** which will be similar to [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/).

Ideally, this newsletter plugin should have such features:

- easy import/export of subscribed users via csv files
- group users by categories (for example WordPress, Web-Design etc; and possibility to send some newsletters to specific categories)
- users can easily subscribe/unsubscribe via the website

Nice-to-have features:

- statistics of subscribed/unsubscribed users
- archive of previous newsletters
- advanced search with various filters
- cleaning of emails duplicates

Can you give some advice or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

I believe I've found a plugin that has all your ideal features called Email Subscribers. It's an open-source plugin that can be easily setup on your WordPress instance. It runs completely locally on your WordPress instance and does not communicate with a third party like MailChimp. It has an option that can import and export subscribed users via a .csv file. It also supports grouping users where you can upload/export users based on their group. It also includes a subscribe and unsubscribe feature too.

## [Email Subscribers](https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-subscribers) (open source)

> Email Subscribers is a fully featured newsletter plugin. It helps you achieve all your newsletter related tasks effectively in one single place.
>
> Email Subscribers plugin has a separate page with the HTML editor. You can easily create HTML newsletters using this editor in around 5 minutes. You also have a separate page to select the include and exclude categories before sending each newsletter. You can quickly import/ export email addresses of registered users and commentators to the subscription list using the import-export option in the plugin.
>
> [image: Screenshot 1]